# How to represents states in numeric representation for Reinforcement learning. ( to Create a Q Table )

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am working on a Q-learning algorithm where I need to construct a formula to create a custom colour by mixing many colours. So the objective here is to generate a formula for all valid custom colors

success forumla - merit with a reward

bad formula - punish the agent with demerits

Basically, I have 10 base colours from which I need to generate custom colours. The basic colours are red, green, blue, white, black,  yellow, etc

I am encoding these basic colours using one - hot encoding

```
red   here is [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
green here is [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
blue  here is [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
white here is [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
black here is [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
yellow     is [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
etc,etc
```

if I want to generate

```
CASE 1: pink color then it is a mix of red + white  ( GOOD FORMULA )
CASE 2: light green colour then it is a mix of green + white  ( GOOD FORMULA )
CASE 3: grey colour then it is a mix of black + white   ( GOOD FORMULA )
CASE 4: purple colour then it is a mix of pink + black  ( GOOD FORMULA )
CASE 5: eggplant colour is purple + green  ( GOOD FORMULA )
CASE 6: BAD colour is purple + black  ( BAD FORMULA )
```

I presume, the state is a colour and the action is selecting the other colour resulting in a custom colour.

If the state is one of the base colours, I can represent the state with the colour (using  one hot encoding).

But if the state is a custom colour, is there a way to represent this in a numerical representation ? ( for CASE 4 , CASE 5 and CASE 6)

I hope, I made my case as much clear as possible. Since there are 10 base colours, the combinatons are massive and hence the states. Not sure how to proceed from here. Any guidance would be of immense help

Comment: Is the amount of color combinations 10 factorial? Or are the custom colors only a combination of 2 base colors.  If it is only a combination of 2 base colors, you can just do multiple hot encoding.  Such as pink being [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...] to represent both white and red being active.

Comment: @RuiNian - thanks for your time and help. Deeply appreciate it.  The amount of color combinations is 10 factorial. But most ( say 60%) of the color combinations results in bad formula and remaining 40% of color combinations results in good formula.